# How can I export ALL notes from Gnote to HTML through command line?

Tags: gnote

I want to export the notes of Gnote. All of them. To HTML or plain text.

It is known that Gnote has a plugin that exports each note to HTML. But I have to do it manually (and takes 4 actions per note using the GUI!) plus, there is no option to export entire notebooks or even all the available notes.

[image]

So, my question regards exactly that point: I looked for a command line tool, gnote option, or even a tomboy trick (after importing the notes from gnote) in order to get all the notes in HTML (one note = one file). No luck. Anyone knows how to do it? I accept any crazy workaround, use of other programs, etc.

Oh!... I forgot to mention that I have 1435 notes (yes I do like to take notes). And they are in GNOTE format. So, 1) the manual export REALLY DOESN'T MAKE SENSE. Please jump that option in your response. And 2) again, the notes are in Gnote, so any solution have to start from there: the gnote db.

Ideally, I would like to access that particular gnote command that exports to HTML and make a loop in bash or something to apply it to each note. The man page of gnote doesn't show any additional info, the debug mode doesn't show me what the export to HTML command do... so, I felt like I needed some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an alternative, check out https://github.com/joshp23/Gnoted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, nobody helped me, so I did it by myself :)

Check this out for instructions on how to install it and use use it. 
Hope it will be useful!

**Install Gnote Exporter to TXT:** 
https://github.com/rhoconlinux/gnote-massive-export-to-txt

This is the final result. All the notes exported to txt. 
[image]

This is how a text note looks like after the export.
[image]

Cheers!